# Automating MsAccess in Windows Application in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, ms-access, automation

I have an window application, in which we are automating MsOffice(word/excel/powerpoint/access).
We already had wrote helper class for word/excel/powerpoint, now we are trying to write helper class for Access.

*In which, we want to write the method to
1 Quit the application(access),
2 Evaluvate Currently Running,
3 Applications(access), 
4 GetorCreate the application(access),
5 run application(access),
6 close the application(access), & etc etc.,

```
What i have tried so far:
```

AccessHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AccessInterop = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

namespace TeTec.Action.Office2013.Access
{
    public static class AccessHelper
    {
        #region Constants

        private static readonly string _accessApplicationObjectStoreKey = "AccessApplication";

        #endregion


        #region Private methods
        private static void QuitApplication(AccessInterop.Application accessApplication)
        {
            if (accessApplication != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    accessApplication.DoCmd.SetWarnings(false);
                    accessApplication.Visible = false;
                    accessApplication.DoCmd.Quit();

                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(accessApplication);

                    accessApplication = null;
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    accessApplication.DoCmd.CloseDatabase();
                    accessApplication.DoCmd.Quit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Ignore
                }
            }
        }

        private static AccessInterop.Application GetOrCreateAccessApplication(IObjectStore objectStore)
        {
            AccessInterop.Application accessApplication = objectStore.Retrieve<AccessInterop.Application>(_accessApplicationObjectStoreKey);
            if (accessApplication == null)
            {
                accessApplication = new AccessInterop.Application();
                objectStore.Store(_accessApplicationObjectStoreKey, accessApplication);
            }

            return accessApplication;
        }

        #endregion


        #region Internal methods
        internal static void Cleanup(IObjectStore objectStore, bool terminate)
        {
            AccessInterop.Application accessApplication = objectStore.Retrieve<AccessInterop.Application>(_accessApplicationObjectStoreKey);
            if (accessApplication != null)
            {
                QuitApplication(accessApplication);
                objectStore.Remove(_accessApplicationObjectStoreKey);
            }

            if (terminate)
                WinUtil.TerminateProcess("access.exe", null, null, true);
        }
        #endregion


        #region Public methods

        #region Basic operation

        public static bool Run(IQuestion question)
        {
            AccessInterop.Application accessApplication = GetOrCreateAccessApplication(question.ObjectStore);
            //AccessInterop.DataAccessPage accesPage = null;


            try
            {
                //Avoid screen flickering or unwanted alerts while initializing

                accessApplication.DoCmd.Echo(false);
                accessApplication.DoCmd.SetWarnings(false);

                //Create a document, if one does not exist already
                //if (accessApplication.catlo == 0)
                //    accesPage = accessApplication.DataAccessPages.a;

                //Activate Word application window
                //accessApplication.Visible = true;
                //accessApplication.ScreenUpdating = true;
                //accessApplication.DisplayAlerts = displayAlertLevel;
                //accessApplication.ActiveWindow.Activate();

                ////Setup application main window
                //if (question.WorkArea != Rectangle.Empty)
                //{
                //    accessApplication.WindowState = AccessInterop.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal;
                //    accessApplication.ActiveWindow.Left = question.WorkArea.Left;
                //    accessApplication.ActiveWindow.Top = question.WorkArea.Top;
                //    accessApplication.ActiveWindow.Width = question.WorkArea.Width;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    accessApplication.WindowState = AccessInterop.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
                //}

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Cleanup(question.ObjectStore, true);
                return false;
            }
        }

    public static void Close(IQuestion question)
    {
                Cleanup(question.ObjectStore, false);
            }

    #endregion

    #endregion
    }
    }
```

GetOrCreateApplication & CleanUpApplication is not working.NOne of the methods are working.

Can any one please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention what is going wrong.

Comment: You say "not working".  What exactly does that mean?  Are those routines running, but producing the wrong result?  Do they not even run?  Do they run, but with errors?

Comment: returning nothing